# AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserver not fired if track ended

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I use UISlider to display the position of the track and AVPlayer for playing the track. m3u8 file.
To show the current position in the track, I do this:

```
timeObserver = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(1, 2), queue: .main) { [weak self] time in
        if let `self` = self {
            self.eventListener?.onEvent(PlayerEvent.progressed(time: time), generetedBy: self)
        }
    }
```

The slider changes its position and everything is fine. But when the track ends slider the slider is not at the end.

Result:

0.0

0.500590782

1.001336673

1.501167803

2.001181077

2.501238459

2.564631671

END

[image: addPeriodicTimeObserver]

But, duration: 2.693

Comment: Change CMTimeMake(1, 2) to CMTimeMake(1, 20000) and try again

Comment: @amergin The slider began to run faster but stopped there.

Comment: Maybe just add an endObserver and animate the slider to 2.693 (or duration) in that? Seems to me that maybe the difference between 2.56 and 2.69 can be explained by processing time.